# Unable to add fourth convolutional layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm pretty new to maching learning and when I was looking at a tutorial for a convolutional neural network I wanted to experiment on my own on how to increase accuracy. However, when I tried to add another convolutional and pooling layer to my model it displayed an error message. This is before I added the layer:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(62))
```

And this is after:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(62))
```

This is the error message it gave me:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_36/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](max_pooling2d_26/MaxPool, conv2d_36/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,64], [3,3,64,64]. site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

This is because you reduce the dimensionality too much inside your network. use `padding='same'` in your convolutional layer to avoid this dimensionality error

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', 
                        input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(62))

model.summary()
```